# jupyter notebook changes the label from numeric to [*] and then gives no output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipynb

jupyter notebook changes the label from numeric to [*] and then gives no output

[image]

When trying to open and run `.ipynb` file in Mozilla FireFiox the jupyter notebook, then after several clicking on the `run` button it starts writting [*] instead of [3],[4] etc and no output results afterwards. Please see the image above.

I have tried to reload the jupyter ipynb file and from time to time it works, but mostly it doesn't

I have downloaded `ipynb` files from this [web](https://github.com/EdwardRaff/Inside-Deep-Learning/blob/main/idlmam.py)

**EDIT** Yes there is

[image]

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes there is, please see my edit.

Comment: Please don't post the console output as an image. It is very hard to read this way. Copy/paste the text into your question. Looks like the kernel died at 20:39. Can you a) post the code that you are running, b) start a fresh jupyter notebook session from console, then open your notebook and run only the two cells in question here; then report the console output again (it looks like quite some time has passed in the logs you have posted)